# Можно ли изменить битрейт USB камеры без декодирования потока?

Tags: видео, ffmpeg, usb, raspberry-pi, gstreamer

Я использую USB-камеру ELP с h264 кодеком на выходе.

Команда Ffmpeg для взятия потока:

```
ffmpeg -i /dev/video1 -c:v copy output.ts
```

В результате я получаю видео с битрейтом 4Мбит/с, что слишком много для моих задач.

Аналогичная ситуация при использовании GSTreamer:

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video1 ! video/x-h264,width=1280,height=720,framerate=30/1 ! mpegtsmux ! filesink location=output.ts
```

Я знаю, что возможное решение проблемы - декодировать h264 кодек, поменять битрейт и кодировать обратно в h264, но данные манипуляции потребляют слишком много процессорной мощности моей NanoPI.

Возможно ли изменение битрейта USB камеры без декодирования потока?

Comment: Пробовали настроить параметры камеры штатными средствами? То есть теми, что для камеры являются штатными.

Comment: Почитайте спецификацию http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_video_device_class там в References первая ссылка. Возможно получится выставить *3.1.2 H.264 Video Frame Descriptors*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблему частично помог решить @nick_n_a , натолкнув на мысль о UVC протоколе.
Некоторые USB камеры поддерживают UVC протокол, который даёт возможность регулировать больший спектр функций, чем v4l2-ctl.

Например, изменить битрейт без перекодирования можно так:

```
gst-launch-1.0 uvch264src initial-bitrate=1500000 average-bitrate=1500000 iframe-period=1000 device=/dev/video0 name=src auto-start=true src.vidsrc ! video/x-h264,width=1280,height=720,framerate=30/1,profile=constrained-baseline ! h264parse ! mpegtsmux ! filesink location=output.ts
```

ВАЖНО! Камеры ELP не поддерживают данный чудесный протокол. Зато всем известная Logitech C920 - да, на ней и была протестирована данная команда.

Если кто-нибудь знает HD USB камеры с поддержкой h.264 кодека и UVC протокола, пишите, буду благодарен.